# Search for all the mp3 files in memory card in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, memory, mp3

I want to get all the audio files (MP3s etc etc) from Memory-card on windows Phone. I don't know how to achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can only access tracks the user has in the music app. This is a restriction of the operating system. There is no way to access sound files of other apps.

You have to use the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) class from the XNA framework. See this [blog post](http://www.ginktage.com/2011/11/how-to-get-the-list-of-songsgenresalbums-from-the-windows-phone-medialibrary/) for a good explanation on how to use it.